# Redis active - active replication across datacenters / Kubernetes clusters

Tags: redis, kubernetes, replication, twemproxy, xdcr

I have deployed a highly available [Redis](https://github.com/antirez/redis/) service on Kubernetes (the redis version used is 4.0.9) with aof persistence. Three sentinel nodes monitoring one master node and two slave nodes. 
I now have the following use case:
Deploy two instances of the kind described above on separate Kubernetes clusters  and keep them in sync. The setup should provide active - active replication.

The possible solutions I have come up with until now are:

1. using Twitter's [twemproxy](https://github.com/twitter/twemproxy) to proxy requests to and from the separate Redis services in the Kubernetes. The issue in this case is that (afaik) [twemproxy](https://github.com/twitter/twemproxy) automatically shards data across the available Redis nodes / clusters, hence the master redis nodes in the configuration described above will not have the same data-sets at any given point in time.
2. Using [XDCRWithKafka](https://github.com/YongMan/XDCRWithKafka). I haven't managed to find any documentation on the use of XDCRWithKafka...
3. Using [HAProxy](https://www.haproxy.org/) in pretty much the same way twemproxy would be used (again, afaik,HAProxy does not support request multicasting)
4. Some custom sln of the sort described in: http://grokbase.com/t/gg/redis-db/123nyg4rfp/multiple-master-going-to-one-slave (although keeping the redis clusters in sync with such a solution while in active - active state does not seem to be that straightforward...)

Any ideas / suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 0):

As far as i have seen, only Dynomite seems to solve this problem. https://github.com/Netflix/dynomite/wiki/Topology

Else one suggestion is to implement our own by having a setup something like this:

DataCenter1:

[multiple redis clients]===>[localProxy-DC1]====> TWEMPROXY-DC1 ===> [Multiple Redis Single Instances with Sentinel]

DataCenter-2:

[localProxy-DC1] ====replicates commands async===> TWEMPROXY-DC2 ====> [Multiple Redis Single Instances with Sentinel]